# Serve static files outside the jar file

Tags: spring-boot

When we build a spring boot web application, the `jar` file contains a `static` folder where the frontend files such as `index.html`, etc are served.  I have another UI project built from React and the build artifacts can be found inside the `build` directory.  Say I have a directory in Linux called `myapp`, and it contains the `jar` file from the springboot app and the `build` folder from my UI project.

```
myapp
  |_ myspringbootapp.jar
  |_ build
       |_ index.html
       |_ etc...
```

Instead of serving the files inside the `static` folder inside the `jar` file, I want spring boot to serve the files from the `build` directory (outside the jar).  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring.web.resources.static-locations` to configure the locations from which static resources will be loaded. By default, its value is `classpath:/META-INF/resources/, classpath:/resources/, classpath:/static/, classpath:/public/`.

To only load resources from `/myapp/build` you would configure `spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/myapp/build/`.

Take care as this will allow your application to serve anything in `/myapp/build`.

Comment: Should it be `spring.resources.static-locations`?

Comment: Not if you're using a supported version of Spring Boot. The property's been `spring.web.resources.static-locations` [since 2.4](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#web-configuration-properties).